# org-store-link: how to make docview default PDF link

Tags: org-mode, pdf, pdf-tools, hyperlinks

Whenever I use `org-store-link` and `org-insert-link` for PDFs, it stores the link as file: type. This will open the link as an external PDF file with my OS PDF viewer.

Is there a way to set up `org-store-link` to use pdftools of docview as the default viewer for when storing links?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to tell `org` to open pdf `file:` links with `pdf-tools`.  Do this thusly:

```
(push '("\\.pdf\\'" . emacs) org-file-apps)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another more indirect approach is to make sure that your `~/.mailcap` file does what you want with PDF files:

```
...
application/pdf; emacsclient %s
...
```

and making sure that you have started the server in your emacs with `M-x server-start`.

It's indirect in that several things have to go "right", but they generally are "right" by default - unless you've changed them of course. The following is Linux-only (I have no idea how/whether MacOS and Windows handle mailcaps):

- `org-file-apps` should include the entry `("\\.pdf\\'" . default)`
- `org-file-apps-gnu` should include the entry `(system . mailcap)`
- `~/.mailcap` should include the stanza above

The trouble of course is that debugging problems involves looking in three places instead of one. OTOH, if you want uniform treatment of PDF files, that's a central place to do it, so many programs that know about `~/.mailcap` will open PDF files in Emacs; if you do the customization in `org-file-apps` only Org mode knows (or at least cares) about it, which, depending on one's point of view, may be considered either a limitation or a feature.

Comment: Thanks, NickD, I have accepted the other answer as it was easier for me to follow and implement as an Emacs beginner.

Comment: I would have done the same.